# 5 seconds grey screen before ubuntu MATE login screen

Tags: boot, screen, mate, ubuntu-mate

When I boot up my PC, first it shows as always asus screen for 1 seconds and then it proceeds with simple gray screen for 5-6 seconds and then it starts to boot into ubuntu MATE.

Can I skip this grey screen?
I recorded what it looks like: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7UkbdDnyz68

Thanks.

Comment: That's normal. It shows a grey screen but is running commands in the background. And the grey screen is inherited from grub.

Comment: Every user experieces this?

Comment: Maybe, but I absolutely do.

Comment: Is there a way I can chage that it shows something? not this blank grey screen?

Comment: Sure! Do you want me to write an answer to that, but it will also change your Grub background as I have already said its, inherited from Grub.

Comment: Ok, write as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open this file as root "/etc/default/grub":

   `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
2. Scroll down and add these lines to the file, with the link to the image that you want as background:

   > #Comment to disable background image
   >    GRUB_BACKGROUND="/path/to/file.png"
3. Save the file by pressing "Ctrl + X", then Y.
4. Still in terminal run:

   `sudo update-grub`

That's it.

**EDIT:** The limits are explained [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Displays).

[A good example](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ijPb8f7oVXU/maxresdefault.jpg).

Comment: Now I get only black screen. Is there any resolution limit?

Comment: @MatjažJerman - Edited.

Comment: Could make it to show any picture I give. I'll just get on with black screen :)

Comment: Even your pic example doesn't work. I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: When you run update-grub, do you see a line such as: Found background image,,,

Comment: Yes, it does find it, but doesnt show it.

Comment: Did you save it in your home directory?

Comment: Well I formated disk, installed windows (I want to dual boot windows sometimes) and then installed ubuntu. Now grub works fine and I'm satisfied with results.

Maybe there was a bug of some sort.

Comment: @MatjažJerman - Oh! strange, learned something new. Thanks!

Comment: I used GRUB customizer to change some grub options. It works fine.
Yes, you learn everyday something new about linux :D

Comment: @MatjažJerman - :P